# Set up a DNS server to mask authoritative records

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

Can I configure a Windows DNS Server to make a scenario whereby I mask the master/authoritative records like microsoft.com, example.com, contoso.com, etc with my own administered records in the local DNS server having different values?

For example, in my development server environment I want to have a development DNS server to resolve the microsoft.com root domain and some of its secondary domains to private IPs on my LAN, instead of forwarding those DNS requests.

I don't want to actually get into DNS zone transfers or delegation proper because this is not a production scenario, and my understanding is some masters would have to be configured to permit DNS slaves to carry out such tasks.  However I want to test by using existing infrastructure and masters, to have something to start from.

This is for academic purposes at the moment. I'm a DNS Server novice so my terminology might be off. If so, I apologize, please extrapolate and answer according to your own experience or point me to answers that might already exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You simply need to add those DNZ zones on your DNS server. Any DNS clients using your DNS server and querying for those domains will get answers from your DNS servers zones.

Note that this has no bearing on anything other than the clients that use your DNS server.

Comment: This works, thanks. 
# create primary zone for microsoft.com  |
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -ZoneName microsoft.com -ZoneFile microsoft.com.dns  |
  |  
# add A record to mask www.microsoft.com to private IP range  |
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name www -ZoneName microsoft.com -IPv4Address 10.0.0.2 -PassThru -Verbose  |
  |
# test local resolution  |
Resolve-DnsName www.microsoft.com -Server localhost  |
# answers with private IP 10.0.0.2  |
  |
# requests not in local zone are forwarded  |
Resolve-DnsName www.example.com -Server localhost  |
# answers with public IP 93.184.216.34